Issue while saving the custom tab field value in Product edit page admin magento2
I have created the custom tab in that created field but while trying to save the field values so not saving value on that field and in post value not showing my custom tab field and i have used this event catalog_product_save_after can anyone know how to solvw that?
**Here is my ui_component
**
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="pricematrix">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price Matrix</item>
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="_custom_tab">
            <htmlContent name="html_content">

                <block class="Test\PriceMatrix\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\CustomTab" name="price_custom_tab" template="Test_PriceMatrix::customtab.phtml"/>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>

**This is my template file
**
<div class="pricematrix-custom-tab-content">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Base Price</label>
        </div>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++): ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="base_price[]" id="base_price_<?= $i ?>" value="">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="[display_base_price][]" id="display_base_price_<?= $i ?>" class="input-text">
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Quantity</label>
        </div>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++): ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="qty[]" id="qty_<?= $i ?>" value="">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="[display_qty][]" id="display_qty_<?= $i ?>" class="input-text">
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
</div>


<style>
    .pricematrix-custom-tab-content {
        display: flex;
    }

    .column {
        padding: 0 15px;
    }

    .field {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .control {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>

**This is my observer file
<?php

namespace Test\PriceMatrix\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class SavePriceMatrix implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $postData = $this->request->getPostValue();

        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("Post Data: " . json_encode($postData));

        if (isset($postData['display_base_price']) && isset($postData['display_qty'])) {
            $displayBasePrice = $postData['display_base_price'];
            $displayQty = $postData['display_qty'];

            $processedBasePrice = json_encode($displayBasePrice);
            $processedQty = json_encode($displayQty);

            $product->setData('display_base_price', $processedBasePrice);
            $product->setData('display_qty', $processedQty);
        }
    }
}

I have tried this code and checked the logs but not showing my custom tab fields in post value logs.

Kindly cross-verify if the custom data is indeed saved in the database. If the custom data is saved in the database, then the issue may be with the display. In that case, you would need to use a plugin to render the saved data.
